# How to create unequal columns using bootstrap col class

Tags: html, css, row, col

I have been assigned to make the below layout using 3 methods.

- Using Div's
- Using CSS Grid System of Bootstrap
- Using Row & Col class of Bootstrap

Here is the demo layout:
[image]

I have made layout using Div's & CSS grid system but I am unable to design the main content & sidebar using row & col classes of bootstrap because It does not allow to make unequal columns.

Is there anyway to achieve this using Col & Row classes of bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap col- classes for creating unequal columns

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12" style="background-color:orange;">12/12</div>
  <div class="col-12" style="background-color:gray;">12/12</div>
  <div class="col-9" style="background-color:wheat;">9/12</div>
  <div class="col-3" style="background-color:aliceblue;">3/12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But Isn't CSS grid?

Comment: CSS grid system is different from Bootstrap Grid system

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap divides a page into 12 sections
[image: Bootstrap]

You can divide sections into `<div class="container"><div>` and then inside into `<div class="row"><div>` and then the row can be modified by `<div class="col-[SCREEN_SIZE]-[NUMBER_OF_SECTIONS]"><div>`.

For SCREEN_SIZE check out: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

NUMBER_OF_SECTIONS: 1-12

Comment: You can also ignore the SCREEN_SIZE component and just write for an example: col-12